# Print data from parallel processes in Python's multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` module in Python to create 2 processes that work on the same live data and are expected to print their respective debugging information and results on the console.

How can that be done? AFAIK, only one of those processes takes over the console used to execute the program and the other process is unable to log its print outputs on any console.

```py
def fa():
    global live_data
    print(f'from fa {live_data}')

def fb():
    global live_data
    print(f'from fb {live_data}')

processes_list=[]
pa=Process(target=fa, args=())
pb=Process(target=fb, args=())
pa.start()
pb.start()
```

I only get the output of one of the functions `fa` or `fb` on the console.

Comment: You could use a logger.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating that ?

Comment: I realized simply using print works for me. You can try `print("fa", flush=True)`

Comment: I realised that the problem with the program not giving back the output was not related to multiprocessing, rather it was with the hardware.... I will close this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, your issue is that variables can't just be shared between processes when multiprocessing. You could, if this is your problem, solve it by using the Manager function from multiprocessing to transfer data instead.

Comment: Nope. I want to log/print the variables created during execution of each process and their outputs.

Comment: Okay that's my misunderstanding then sorry.